# Android crop intent doesn't work on system gallery app but works on 3rd-party app

Tags: crop, android-gallery

I try to pick an image from sdcard and then crop it.
ACTION_PICK is OK, but when i call ACTION_CROP, my system gallery app (I call it as A) can't done the action, but another app (B) can.

 I tried the following cases:

 1/ Pick by A and then crop by A => pick OK, crop fail

 2/ Pick by B and then crop by A => the same as first case.

 3/ Pick by A and then crop by B => every things OK.

 4/ Pick by B and then crop by B => every things OK.

 So my temporary conclusion is: my system app can't do the crop action with my code (may be i forgot something). Here is my code:

 `ACTION_PICK:`

```
public Intent galleryIntent() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    return galleryIntent;
}
```

`ACTION_CROP:`

```
public Intent cropIntent(Uri inUri, int outputX, int outputY,
        boolean isScale) {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(inUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", outputX);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", outputY);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", outputX);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", outputY);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", isScale);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    return cropIntent;
}
```

My onActivityResult method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY:
            imageUri = data.getData();
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent(imageUri,
                    500, 500, true), REQUEST_CODE_CROP);
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CROP:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap tempBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            imgvMain.setImageBitmap(null);
            imgvMain.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        imageUri = null;
    }
}
```

Am i missing somethings? 

 Thank for your attention!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Stock gallery app is crashing when I am selecting that app for crop. What solution did you apply?

Comment: @CodeKrish try this one: https://github.com/biokys/cropimage.
<br>
And don't forget to vote my question up if this help you :P

Comment: I was able to find the cause and fix it without creating my own crop feature. I have posted the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code successfully for Android 2.2 and up:

It opens a selection of apps that can get image files e.g. the Gallery app. If the selected app can crop, it will also do so.

The cropped image will be saved to the supplied temp file.

(note the small difference for KITKAT).

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", Constants.IMAGE_WIDTH); 
        intent.putExtra("outputY", Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT); 
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1); 
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1); 
        intent.putExtra("scale", true); 
        intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(<a temp file created somewhere>));
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } 
        else 
        {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CROP);
```

EDIT:
I ended up using custom cropping using: https://github.com/biokys/cropimage. It was very easy and I had no more troubles with cropping :-)

Comment: Please figure me out what is the diffrent from your and mine, i guess there is no different.

Comment: I explain how to deal with KITKAT...

Other than that you did a good job

Comment: Perhaps you should do what I did.

I added custom cropping using: 
[https://github.com/biokys/cropimage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage).

It was very easy and I had no more troubles with cropping :-)

Answer (score 1):

I checked the logs by filtering with **gallery3d** and found out that the stock app is not getting permission to access the uri. Hence it's behaving unexpectedly. That behaviour is different for different platforms.

Solution:

1. get the uri of the selected image in onActivityResult() for intent ACTION_PICK.
2. save the image temporarily.
3. create new URI from the saved image.
4. pass the new URI to com.android.camera.action.CROP.

Sample code: (Dont copy paste. for simplicity ,I have removed the error checks and async tasks.)

```
public void pickCroppedPhoto(){
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    populateCropExtras(activity, photoPickerIntent);
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent , REQUEST_CODE_PICK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK ) {
        File mainImage = saveUriInFile( this,
                                    data.getData(),
                                    getTempFileForMainImage());
        if (null == mainImage) {
            handleImageSelectionFailure();
        }else {
            try {
               Uri mainFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mainImage);
               performCrop(this,mainFileUri);
            }catch(Exception e){
                handleImageSelectionFailure();
            }
        }
    }else if ( requestCode == PIC_CROP ){
        postImageSelection(data.getData());
    }
}
```

Here is my performCrop code which is similar to that of the question.

```
public static boolean performCrop(Activity activity, Uri picUri) {
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        if (populateCropExtras(activity, cropIntent)) return false;
        activity.startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        return true;
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        String errorMessage = "Device doesn't support crop!";
        Log.w(PhotoPickerUtil.class.getCanonicalName(), errorMessage);
        return false;
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        String errorMessage = "Error while getting temporary file from external storage";
        Log.w(PhotoPickerUtil.class.getCanonicalName(), errorMessage);
        return false;
    }
}

private static void populateCropExtras(Activity activity, Intent cropIntent) throws IOException { {
    // set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");


    // indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);

    // indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());

    Uri tempUri = Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(activity));
    cropIntent.putExtra("output", tempUri);
}
```